# Optimal log file size for BerkeleyDB-JE

Tags: berkeley-db-je

As I try to understand performance issues with our application, I came across a configuration option ***je.log.fileMax*** for BerkeleyDB-JE. However, I can't find any description/documentation when and how one must change this value, if at all.

I have now ~ 6GB in ~600 files. The data changes quite intensive. Should I care about log file size and if yes, is there a guidelines or best practice?